# Is it possible to change the previewed text of an e-mail, with a tag or similar?

Tags: html, email

I have an e-mail I'm sending programmatically from a template, the source looks vaguely like this:

`<img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/header.png" height=75 alt="logo">
<hr>
<p>{content}</p>`

When the e-mail appears in outlook, it's preview (usually the first line or so) appears as

```
Joe Bloggs
E-mail Subject Here
< http://www.mysite.com/images/header.png>
```

This is pretty crap looking. Is there a tag I can use, maybe a meta tag of some kind, to tell it about preview text, or another way of doing it?

Comment: This is internal behaviour of Outlook, which will sanitize the html before displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is commonly referred to as a pre-header. Your email client (Outlook) will automatically display the first content of your email. There are methods to determine what that content actually is, the most basic of all is to simply include your desired text at the top of your email.

[This guide](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3628/a-practical-guide-to-email-preheaders/) from Campaign Monitor has a technique to hide the text in the email itself, but still show in the preview.